# How to install ATI Catalyst driver on low resolution (640x440) screen?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, resolution, safe-mode, amd-catalyst

I have used DriverSweeper to clean my OS up from all ATI drivers. Now I can only boot in safe-mode with 640x480 screen resolution. ATI Catalyst setup window is bigger then my screen and I can't see buttons "Next", "Cancel" etc. 
How can I install ATI Catalyst driver? Are there command line arguments for setup.exe?

Windows XP 32

ATI Catalyst Control Center and Display Driver version 11-1

Comment: do you try alt+space(title bar menu) and size option to resize window

Comment: there is no resize option, only move and close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the freeware ALTmove ( http://www.deskex.com/AltMove/index.asp) and run the program then press the ALT key and drag your installation window by clicking anywhere on it(similar to linux system) and you can see the buttons now.